# Convergence uniform implies convergence $L^p$ on $\mathbb R$ or not?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Do you have a counter exemple / proof that if
$$ \sup |f-f_n| \to 0 \implies \|f-f_n\|_{L^p} \to 0$$

Meaning that on the real line, if a sequence of functions converges uniformly to something, then so is it in $L^p$ spaces, for $p >1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's obviously true on bounded set. On $\mathbb R$, you can consider $$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\boldsymbol 1_{[0,n^p]}(x).$$

Comment: The important part is that measure of $\mathbb R$ is infinite (or, more exactly, there are subsets of $\mathbb R$ with arbitrary large measure), not topology (though of course all compacts in $\mathbb R$ has finite measure).